# SharePoint online site script

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-metadata, json

I'm havin' trouble with adding a managed metadata column trough JSONsitetemplate.

When adding a 'self-made' column I get an error 'parameter Internalname references a resource that coud be found'

When using a out-of-the-box-column this error doesn't show.

I've tried different custom-site-column and waiting even like 48h.

```
    {
  "verb": "createSPList",
  "listName": "Administration",
  "templateType": 101,
  "subactions": [
    {
      "verb": "setTitle",
      "title": "Administration"
    },
    {
      "verb": "setDescription",
      "description": "DocumentLibrary for Administration"
    },
    {
      "verb": "addSiteColumn",
      "internalName": "playDocType",
      "addToDefaultView": true
    }
  ]
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you had already made sure that the referred 'Site Column' is already present in the site or being created before using?

As per Microsoft documentation "addSiteColumn - Subaction to add a **previously defined site column directly to a list** (existing or created through the site script)."

Comment: Yeah, I did ... I've created on hubsite, main sitecollection, even on the site itself before updating to new sitetemplate. Right now, I'm looking into Plumsail for a solution.

Comment: Hi, I know you have checked all possible areas, but please go to the 'site columns' section on your site and check if the column is available. Then open the column for edit and check the url to make sure the internal name is same. You can also try creating new document library manually and use 'add from existing site columns' link to find your site column and add to the library. My guess, either the column is not defined as a site column or it is having some different 'internal name'.

Comment: Hi UBK. Meanwhile I got a solution. When adding the sitecolumn to the CThub and creating a new teamsite I had to wait 1h+ before the custom-made column was available. Now I'm trying to find a work-around so I don't have to apply a site-template twice ... If you have any suggestions, they are welcome :) Thx for your advice!

Comment: Hi @Emiel yes, you would have to wait for some time after creating site column/ content types in Content Type Hub site collection, since SharePoint publishes it using a job which runs in a pre-defined schedule. Also, each sites which subscribes the content type from the CTHub, has a content type subscriber job (which runs around in 4 hours interval), which makes the content types to be available before you can use them.